# Customize title of HTML output of Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

How do I customize the title (id="titlearea") of of html output of Doxygen?
I'd like to make parts of the text bold.

Doxygen creates a default page title based on `PROJECT_NAME`, `PROJECT_BRIEF` and `PROJECT_LOGO`, but those options don't take html tags, so that I could customize parts of the text that goes in each.

I couldn't find a way to make the title different from `PROJECT_NAME`.

Comment: Did you have a look at the possibilities of specifying your own HTML_HEADER( in doxygen configuration file, Doxyfile) ?

Comment: I didn't because I didn't want to redo the whole header. But I'll do it if no other option is presented. I was thinking of some property somewhere that overrides page title, as setting the title to be the same as project name seems quite ungeneralistic.Thx

Comment: it is not redoing the whole html_header (as you can get the default with doxygen -w) just in the html_header.html or defining your own css for the projectname.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the customized `header.html` file to achieve this. Use the following command to generate the doxygen html templates:

```
doxygen -w html header.html footer.html customdoxygen.css
```

Then edit the `header.html` file. Search for the `$projectname` variable in the `header.html` file, and then we can add whatever HTML tags or CSS styles with it. To make it bold, change the original contents as bellow, so it could be bold in the generated html.

```
<strong>$projectname</strong>
```

Then set the file in the `doxygen.conf` file, it will pick up the customized header file.

```
HTML_HEADER = header.html
```

Well if you want to make it parts of the text bold, we have to make some tricky things to use the available `doxygen.conf` variables for different purpose, like:

```
index.html
Revision <a target="_blank" href="http://hg.openjdk.java.net/" title="$projectname">$projectnumber</a> last modified at <code>$projectbrief</code>
```

where we make

- `$projectnumber` (`PROJECT_NUMBER` in `doxygen.conf`) contains the revision number
- `$projectbrief` (`PROJECT_BRIEF` in `doxygen.conf`) contains the last modified date